# How to change font size (specifically chevron size) of BreadcrumbBar control?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, winui-3

I am designing an app using Windows App SDK and WinUI 3 and trying to figure out a way to change the size of the chevrons in [BreadcrumbBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/breadcrumbbar). I created a data item template to change the styling of the BreadcrumbBarItem(s) but now need to adjust the font size of the chevrons to match that of the text.

Essentially I am trying match the settings app design in Windows 11, as seen in the image below. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

[Windows 11 Settings App - BreadcrumbBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDzX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BreadcrumbBars;

public record Item(string Text, double FontSize, double Width);

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Item> Items = new()
    {
        new Item(Text: "Item#1", FontSize: 30.0, Width: 300.0),
        new Item(Text: "Item#2", FontSize: 20.0, Width: 200.0),
        new Item(Text: "Item#3", FontSize: 10.0, Width: 100.0),
    };
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid.Resources>
    <!-- You can find this in the generic.xaml. -->
    <x:Double x:Key="BreadcrumbBarChevronFontSize">30</x:Double>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid>
    <BreadcrumbBar ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <TextBlock
                    Width="{x:Bind Width}"
                    FontSize="{x:Bind FontSize}"
                    Text="{x:Bind Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </BreadcrumbBar.ItemTemplate>
    </BreadcrumbBar>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am trying to change the size of the chevrons that split each breadcrumb. I've already figured out how to change the font size of the items.

Comment: Sorry. I update my answer.

Comment: Wow, such an easy solution I spent so much time trying to figure out. Thank you!